# jQuery on click the class is being added to a random list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code that upon clicking a list item, adds a class to that particular item, but removes it from the rest of li items.

The added class makes some style changes.

Here's what my problem is that the style changes are happening on random list items, even though the class is added to the correct list item. I have no idea why is it behaving that way

Here are a few snippets of my code. I can't really post the whole code, because it consists of three files and that would just over populate this place. Please follow the link to plunkr.

```
<div class="plans-wrap twelve1">
    <div class="plans-one">
        <h1 class="plans-one-header">Plans</h1>
        <div class="plans-select-wrapper">
            <div class="plans-select">
                <img src="assets/img/arrow.png" alt="" class="hide back-plans">
                <div class="list-wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="twelve1" class="selected-plan">12 Hours(1M)</li>
                        <li id="twenty1">24 Hours(1M)</li>
                        <li id="twelve3">12 Hours(3M)</li>
                        <li id="twenty3">24 Hours(3M)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <img src="assets/img/arrow.png" alt="" class="next-plans">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="plans-description">
            <h4>Workspace</h4>
            <p>A dedicated desk and access to community, benefits and events for a month.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="plans-description">
            <h4>Credits</h4>
            <p>144 credits per month to book conference rooms and utilise for other TFC benefits.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="plans-description">
            <h4>Access</h4>
            <p>1 location, 1 Month, Mon-Sat (8 AM to 9 PM).</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<style>
    .plans-select>.list-wrapper>ul>li {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        /*left: 0;*/
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        margin-left: 4%;
        /*padding: 1rem;*/
        color: #9B9B9B;
        text-align: center;
        transition: left 0.4s;
    }

    .plans-select>.list-wrapper>ul>li:nth-of-type(1) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .plans-select>ul>li:nth-of-type(1) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .plans-one-header {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 44px;
    }

    .plans-select>.list-wrapper>ul>.selected-plan {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #EF5138;
        color: #EF5138;
    }

    .plans-description {
        margin-top: 3.3rem;
    }

    .plans-description:nth-of-type(1) {
        margin-top: 2.1rem;
    }

    .plans-description>h4 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        line-height: 1.57rem;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    .plans-description>p {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        line-height: 1.57rem;
    }

    .plans-two>.plan-amenities {
        margin-top: 2.5rem;
    }

    .plan-amenities>.plan-amenity-icon {
        margin-left: 1.4rem;
    }

    .plan-amenities>.plan-amenity-icon:nth-of-type(1) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .plans-wrap {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .plans-two>.pricing-btn {
        width: 65%;
        background-color: #EF5138;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 1.4rem 0;
        border: none;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 4rem;
        margin-left: 0.8rem;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;    
    }
</style>
<script>
    $('.list-wrapper > ul > li').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('ul').children().removeClass('selected-plan');
        $(this).closest('.pricing-detail-wrapper').children('.plans-wrap').addClass('hide');
        var identity = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.' + identity + '.plans-wrap').removeClass('hide');
        $(this).addClass('selected-plan');
    });
</script>
```

Here's the link my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/sjY7n3VCUJJHsTN01DyX?p=preview

I'd really appreciate some help with it. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the callback of the "click" event as below:

```
$('.list-wrapper > ul > li').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.pricing-detail-wrapper').find('ul').children().removeClass('selected-plan');
  $(this).closest('.pricing-detail-wrapper').children('.plans-wrap').addClass('hide');
  var identity = $(this).attr('id');
  var $wrap = $('.' + identity + '.plans-wrap');
  $wrap.removeClass('hide');
  $wrap.find("#" + $(this).attr("id")).addClass('selected-plan');
});
```

### WHY

U have multiple .plans-wrap, so the .selected-plan you modified is not the one will show. U should find the correct .selected-plan to modify.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got excited when this worked, that I accidentally clicked downvote, then clicked upvote thrice :D  Can you point me to some sort of document where I can read more on this because I haven't faced such problem before, so it would be good to get a better understanding of it. 

Thank you once again.

Comment: @AyushBahuguna  Well, your code is built with jquery. U can get the document of it from http://api.jquery.com/. Is this what u want?

Comment: No, I wanted to know more about how jQuery deals with multiple similar dom items. What's the logic behind it. Edit: I wanted to read more on my particular situation. Didn't understand why having multiple plans wrap should affect if I use .closest() also, how does this affect the classes being added to list items

Comment: It's a big topic then. I believe that u can find what u want in any jquery tutorial book.  BTW, the problem u r facing is somehow complicated, u'd better check it later after reading some tutorials.